# Split a given PDF file using PDFMerge PHP

Tags: php, pdf, split, pdf-generation

I'm using PDFMerger to split a given PDF file, I want to split this file page by page, I'm trying with this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$cont;$i++){<br>
$pdf -> addPDF('Dubai.pdf',$i);<br>
$pdf -> merge('file','hello'.$i.'.pdf');<br>
}
```

`$cont` is a counter, the value of `$cont` is 2, it means that two files must be created and certainly it does, but when I open those files the first contain the first page (this is good), but the second one contains the first and the second page...

What am I doing wrong?

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is exactly what you'd programmed: You add several times the same file to the `$pdf` instance. And call `merge()` after the additional document was added.

So you just have to re-init the `$pdf` instance in your loop:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$cont;$i++){
    $pdf = new PDFMerger();
    $pdf->addPDF('Dubai.pdf',$i);
    $pdf->merge('file','hello'.$i.'.pdf');
}
```